# PHP: How to mass replace $_POST[...] with strip_tags($_POST[...])

Tags: php, forms, input, sanitize, strip-tags

I'm currently recovering from a nasty XSS attack, and realized I never sanitized inputs on several of the forms on my site.  I used Notepad++'s Find In Files feature to search for `$_POST` in all my PHP files, and got almost 5,000 results.  Now, I really don't want to go and manually add `strip_tags` to every one of those results, but a replace-all wouldn't do the trick... and I'm a total noob when it comes to things like regular expressions.

Is there any way to make this a little less tedious?

Answer (score 18):

Just use [`array_map()`](http://php.net/array_map).

```
$Clean = array_map('strip_tags', $_POST);
```

Or if you want it to go back to the `$_POST` variable:

```
$_POST = array_map('strip_tags', $_POST);
```

It's probably a better idea though to use a different variable and change all occurrence of `$_POST` to `$Clean` in your files.

Answer (score 7):

Hmm, I think [`array_walk_recursive`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php) would do the trick:

```
function custom_strip(&$val, $index) {
   $val = strip_tags($val);
}
array_walk_recursive($_POST, 'custom_strip');
```

Answer (score 2):

you can put this in a file (e.g safe.php)

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
  $_POST[$key] = is_array($key) ? $_POST[$key]: strip_tags($_POST[$key]);
}
```

Then put `require_once("safe.php");` in every each of your php files (or a file that all of your php file already included )
It's an ugly hack.. but it may save your time.

Comment: This will fail to protect from XSS when there are form fields whith names like `foo[bar]` or `foo[]` which PHP automatically converts to arrays.

Comment: @Tgr: yeah, this will absolutely fail like you said, but I think he got the idea to customize according to what he need

Answer (score 0):

Very simple. Put this on top of your every file OR in a common header file which gets called in the very beginning every time:

```
function mystriptag(&$item)
{
    $item = strip_tags($item);
}

array_walk($_POST, mystriptag);
```

Comment: This will fail to protect from XSS when there are form fields whith names like `foo[bar]` or `foo[]` which PHP automatically converts to arrays.

Answer (score 0):

You could just [`array_map`](http://php.net/array_map) `strip_tags` to `$_POST`, but it is much nicer to write a custom function for obtaining data from it:

```
function post_data($name) {
    global $post_cache;
    if (in_array($name, $post_cache)) {
        return $post_cache[$name];
    }
    $val = $_POST[$name];
    if (is_string($val)) {
        $val = strip_tags($val);
    } else if (is_array($val)) {
        $val = array_map('strip_tags', $val);
    }
    $post_cache[$name] = $val;
    return $val;
}
```

This will make your code more readable (others looking into it will generally assume that `$_POST['foo']` is the data in form field `foo`, not somethin you have already preprocessed), won't cause you problems with plugins or libraries which try to access $_POST directly, makes it easy to add more logic to `$_POST` preprocessing (unescape when [magic quotes](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php) are enabled is a common one) without hunting down all the places in your code where you have used POST data, and saves you from huge headaches when you realize there are a few POST fields where you do need HTML tags. Generally, it is a really bad idea to directly change any of the superglobals.

Also, it is better to sanitize data on output, not on input. Different uses will require different methods, for example, if you use

```
<div class="user_photo">
   <img src="<?php echo photo_path($user_id) ?>" alt="<?php echo $user_name ?>" />
</div>
```

then `$user_name` is an XSS attack vector, and `strip_tags` does not help against it at all; you would need [htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php). If user data is used as an URL, you would need yet another method to defend against `javascript:` URLs and so on.